# Why is $\frac{4k -1}{2} \equiv 1 \pmod 4$?

Tags: number-theory

Why is $\frac{4k -1}{2} \equiv 1 \pmod 4$?

I need some help with understanding this...

The original problem was:

find the set of Numbers in which $ f(z)=\frac{1}{1- sin(z)} $ is not defined. This happens When $ sin(z) = 1 $

And The solutions would be When $ z = (4k + 1)\pi/2. $ And then someone said: $ \frac{4k-1}{2} $ are the Numbers congruent to $ 1 \pmod 4 $

Comment: How are you dividing by $2$?  $2$ doesn't have an inverse mod $4$.  Also $(4k-1)/2$ is not even an integer.

Comment: If $k$ is an integer, then $4k - 1$ is odd, so $(4k-1)/2$ is not divisible by 2. You may want to check the original problem.

Comment: Give us the original question.

Comment: The original problem was: find the set of Numbers in which f(z)=1/(1- sin(z)) is not defined. This happens When sin(z) = 1 And The solutions would be When z = (4k + 1)Pi/2. And then someone said: 4k-1/2 are the Numbers congruent to 1 mod 4

Comment: Do you mean $4k-\frac{1}{2}$ or $\frac{4k-1}{2}$? Not that it matters; neither are integers (assuming $k$ is an integer) - and that seems to be the end of your question. I don't see what these numbers have to do with $(4k+1)\frac{\pi}{2}$ anyway, or understand who this "someone" is.

Comment: "Someone" is a friend with Whom i was solving the problem. He spontaneusly said that  $ (4k-1)/2 $ are the Numbers congruent to 1 mod 4, And i could not agree or disagree with the comment because I did not understand it.

Comment: The integers congruent to $1$ mod $4$ are all of the form $4k+1$ (which is exactly what you have). What does $\frac{4k-1}{2}$ have to do with that? If you want to know what $a$ mod $n$ means, look up "modular arithmetic."

Comment: If k is an integer, then 4k−1 is odd, so (4k−1)/2 is not divisible by 2. Just one question: didn't You mean "(4k−1) is not divisible by 2"?

Comment: Stretching the congruence notation a bit,  we could say when $\frac{2z}{\pi}\equiv 1 \pmod{4}$. But there is no point to putting it that way, it makes things look more mysterious than they are. Less mysteriously we could say when $2z=n\pi$, where $n$ is an integer congruent to $1$ modulo $4$.

Answer (score 1):

They didn't mean it literally. As you said, $\sin(z)=1$ exactly when $z= \pi/2 + 2k \pi,$  $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. Another way to write this would be $z = \pi/2 (1+4k)=\frac{n\pi}{2}$, for $n = 4k+1$. In other words, the function $f(z)$ is undefined exactly when $z = n \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $n \equiv 1$ (mod  $4)$.